# Why have maps stopped working with the latest Google Maps update?

Tags: android, google-maps

I've recently finished building an app which shows the location of some local business. But since the most recent Google Maps update, when I try to show the location of a business in the map, it shows me a message saying "No results for posx, posy". Here is the code I've been using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + posx + ", " + posy + " (" + name+ ")"));
startActivity(intent);
```

What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, if you start navigation without enabling **gps** and then enable it while the app is running, it doesn't sense that **gps** is **on**. Its just because it asks if the gps is on when it first turns on. The solution would be that you need to enable **gps** before entering the app, or if you forget, just back out of the app and re-enter.Also can stop updates to fix the issue.

Also have a look at it:

- [Google Services Bug Causing Location Issues, Google Working On A
  Fix](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/05/24/google-services-bug-causing-location-issues-for-htc-owners-google-working-on-a-fix/)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the message displayed is not "Location not found" but "No results for posx, posy".